# Intellij: Making a project dependent on another project?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, intellij-idea, ide

I am new to using Intellij and I am facing a problem. I have a project, which is dependent on another project and this second project is integrated using maven repository. So when I work on my project, maven handles everything perfectly and everything is working. But the second project is under development and there are frequent updates which are not in maven repository yet. So what I want to do is to make my first project directly dependent on the second project(it is present in my local system). So that the second project is referred directly from the code and not maven repo. Is it possible in Intellij. I have done this in Eclipse but not able to do it in Intellij. Any help will be usesful.

Thanks

Comment: did you get it working ? I'm trying since last 1 day but no luck. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000322004-Adding-Project-Dependancy-is-not-working.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to configure this in IntelliJ IDEA's Project properties (cmd + ; on Mac, ctrl + alt + shift + s on Windows/Linux).  Select "Modules", select the dependencies tab on the right, and add the dependent module to the module.

Comment: So, Modules in IntelliJ are similar to projects in Eclipse? Or Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: They are similar, although not exactly the same. For more details see [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/module.html).

Comment: @Trisha, It appears to me that you haven't answered the question.  You don't describe any way for one project to depend on another project.  And the docs you link to explicitly state that "modules exist and are functional only in the context of a project" which means there's no way to use modules to make on project depend on another.  Am I correct to understand that the real answer is "sorry OP, you can't do this"?

Comment: No that's not correct - the terminology here is confusing. The OP is talking about Maven projects, which translate into IntelliJ modules. The documentation which says projects can't depend on each other means IntelliJ projects. So maven projects can be made to depend on each other (as modules) but IntelliJ projects cannot depend on each other.

Comment: @EdNorris I think he suggests that. I have just hit the same issue as OP after coming from Eclipse, and it seems that IntelliJ Projects are somewhat similar to Eclipse Workspaces, and IntelliJ Modules are more like Eclipse projects.